# Understand the need of affine connection

Tags: differential-geometry

I can't understand why textbook says that directional derivative cannot be defined for general manifold, and a separate affine connection is needed.

Assume there are two vector fields $X$ and $Y$. In particular, you have a tangent vector at point $p$ called $X_p$. To find the derivative of $Y$ at $p$ in the direction of $X_p$, why can't you just operate $X_p = a^i\partial_i$ on $Y_p = b^j \partial_j$ component-wise?

By component-wise, I meant differentiate the component smooth function $b^j$ with respect to $X_p$. It seems that a smooth real valued function can still be differentiated by a vector field without connection?

Comment: "component-wise"?

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown I updated the question a bit to explain myself better. But to be honest, since I don't understand differential geometry well enough, I probably messed up the concepts in my mind. It would be appreciated if you can explain why affine connection is needed when we already got $X_p$ as a differentiation operator.

Comment: For your definition to make sense, you need to have "constant" vector fields $\partial_j$ ... which, of course, we have with the standard coordinates in Euclidean space but not otherwise.

Comment: @TedShifrin I will try asking in another way. I saw in the textbook that you can differentiate scalar field with respect to a vector field fine using the vector field as a differential operator, but you have to invent mechanism of connection in order to do it for vector field. Why is that the case?

Comment: Directional derivative of a function is just that, just the differentiable structure needed. You tell me how to differentiate a vector field on a surface in $\Bbb R^3$. You might read my diff geo text, linked in my profile, to learn some concrete stuff.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that the vector field you get from componentwise directional derivative depends on choice of the coordinate system.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I'm still confused. Are you talking about the dependence of coordinate system of the vector field **being differentiated** or the vector field **used as differentiation direction**? Maybe that's related with one of my comment? Why is scaler field can be differentiated without problem using just the directional vector field as an differential operator? Can you elaborate a bit more?

Comment: The problem concerns components of the vector field which is being differentiated. If these are $Y^i$ in one coordinate system, then in another one they take the form $\sum_k A^i_k Y^k$, where $A$ is the Jacobi matrix, which is not a constant. By Leibniz rule, the pointwise derivative of $Y$ in the two coordinate systems is not related by the $A$ matrix (as for any honest vector field), but contains also a term with derivatives of $A$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Can I ask if scalar field derivatives always agree independent on the coordinate system? If so, can I ask for a reference for such a proof?

Answer (score 0):

What you're describing is the contraction of exterior derivative of $Y$ by $X$, $\textrm{d}Y(X)$. This can be viewed as the trivial affine connection, as the connection matrix is $0$. In $\mathbb{R}^n$ this coincides with Levi-Civita connection of the Euclidean metric.

In fact, one can always pick coordinates at a point such that a connection matrix vanishes at that point (Riemann Normal coordinates in the case of the Levi-Civita connection).

Alternatively, if one were to naively differentiate 'Y with respect to X' like any function, one has $$X (Y)= X^i{\partial_i}(Y^j{\partial_j}) = X^i ({\partial_i}(Y^j)\partial_j +X^iY^j{\partial_i}({\partial_j}).$$ The issue here is that this is no longer a first order operation, as we are dealing with the second derivative of coordinates.

This leads to the definition another type of directional derivative, the Lie derivative $\mathcal{L}_X$.
The intuition here is that $\mathcal{L}_X$ shows how the vector field $Y$ evolves over the integral curves of $X$, but one can show that $\mathcal{L}_X(Y)=[X,Y]$.

Comment: How do you define $dY$ on a general smooth manifold? $Y$ is not a differential form